# Como modificar o tamanho da fonte dos eixo em Python matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python

Boa tarde.
Gostaria de saber como posso aumentar a fonte nos eixos quando gero um gráfico utilizando matplotlib.pyplot.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 16
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 16
```

Answer (score 1):

Importando a biblioteca como

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Para alterar a fonte nos eixos do gráfico, escreva antes do seu plot

```
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 20
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 20
```

para alterar os parâmetros do tamanho da fonte em cada um dos eixos. No lugar do 20 coloque o tamanho que preferir.

Se quiser alterar o tamanho das fontes da legenda como um todo, escreva antes do seu plot

```
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})
```

Se quiser saber mais detalhes, veja em https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html